# How to identify the image index correctly in horizontal scroll viewer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a horizontal scrollviewer with images.I need to identify the image when user clicks on it.How to identify the image index from horizontal scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `ViewPager` (as per the tag assigned to this question), when you inflate each view you can set a `OnClickListener` and at this point you know which page (or image) you are creating.

Comment: OnClickListener is already added.But when how to  get the name or index of image from it?